# Is it possible to make my CREATE2 factory so that the calculated address is totally independent of the address my factory is deployed on?

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly, create2

Is it possible to make my CREATE2 factory so that the calculated address is totally independent of the address my factory is deployed on.

For example, this is the formula listed on solidity-by-example book, where he uses address(this) as a param:

I want that value to be replaced by any address of my choice that can be passed as a function argument.[image]
Is something like this possible?

I don't see a way to specify that in the normal CREATE2 calls that are made using in-line assembly in solidity_lang

Answer (score 3):

No, that's a core functionality of Ethereum. it can't be altered from outside. Also this type of functionality can introduce more attack vectors.